# Python error when trying to print

Tags: printing

I have been running ubuntu 22.04 for a while now and have printed many things.  All of a sudden I am not able to print.  I am seeing the following errors in the /var/log.  Can someone help me out?

```
Mar 21 10:20:41 birch org.gnome.ControlCenter.SearchProvider[253288]: File "/usr/share/system-config-printer/printerproperties.py", line 1425, in load

Mar 21 10:20:41 birch org.gnome.ControlCenter.SearchProvider[253288]:     option.reinit (value, supported=supported)

Mar 21 10:20:41 birch org.gnome.ControlCenter.SearchProvider[253288]: File "/usr/share/system-config-printer/options.py", line 368, in reinit

Mar 21 10:20:41 birch org.gnome.ControlCenter.SearchProvider[253288]:     OptionAlwaysShown.reinit (self, original_value, supported=supported)

Mar 21 10:20:41 birch org.gnome.ControlCenter.SearchProvider[253288]: File "/usr/share/system-config-printer/options.py", line 229, in reinit

Mar 21 10:20:41 birch org.gnome.ControlCenter.SearchProvider[253288]:     self.set_widget_value (self.original_value)

Mar 21 10:20:41 birch org.gnome.ControlCenter.SearchProvider[253288]: File "/usr/share/system-config-printer/options.py", line 254, in set_widget_value

Mar 21 10:20:41 birch org.gnome.ControlCenter.SearchProvider[253288]:     index = self.combobox_map.index (ipp_value)

Mar 21 10:20:41 birch org.gnome.ControlCenter.SearchProvider[253288]: ValueError: 0 is not in list

Mar 21 10:20:41 birch org.gnome.ControlCenter.SearchProvider[253288]: Continuing anyway..

Mar 21 10:20:41 birch org.gnome.ControlCenter.SearchProvider[253288]: Caught non-fatal exception.  Traceback:

Mar 21 10:20:41 birch org.gnome.ControlCenter.SearchProvider[253288]: File "/usr/share/system-config-printer/printerproperties.py", line 1425, in load

Mar 21 10:20:41 birch org.gnome.ControlCenter.SearchProvider[253288]:     option.reinit (value, supported=supported)

Mar 21 10:20:41 birch org.gnome.ControlCenter.SearchProvider[253288]: File "/usr/share/system-config-printer/options.py", line 229, in reinit

Mar 21 10:20:41 birch org.gnome.ControlCenter.SearchProvider[253288]:     self.set_widget_value (self.original_value)

Mar 21 10:20:41 birch org.gnome.ControlCenter.SearchProvider[253288]: File "/usr/share/system-config-printer/options.py", line 254, in set_widget_value

Mar 21 10:20:41 birch org.gnome.ControlCenter.SearchProvider[253288]:     index = self.combobox_map.index (ipp_value)

Mar 21 10:20:41 birch org.gnome.ControlCenter.SearchProvider[253288]: ValueError: 0 is not in list

Mar 21 10:20:41 birch org.gnome.ControlCenter.SearchProvider[253288]: Continuing anyway..

Mar 21 10:20:41 birch org.gnome.ControlCenter.SearchProvider[253288]: Traceback (most recent call last):

Mar 21 10:20:41 birch org.gnome.ControlCenter.SearchProvider[253288]:   File "/usr/share/system-config-printer/system-config-printer.py", line 1844, in on_edit_activate

Mar 21 10:20:41 birch org.gnome.ControlCenter.SearchProvider[253288]:     self.dests_iconview_item_activated (self.dests_iconview, paths[0])

Mar 21 10:20:41 birch org.gnome.ControlCenter.SearchProvider[253288]:   File "/usr/share/system-config-printer/system-config-printer.py", line 597, in dests_iconview_item_activated

Mar 21 10:20:41 birch org.gnome.ControlCenter.SearchProvider[253288]:     self.propertiesDlg.show (name, host=self.connect_server,

Mar 21 10:20:41 birch org.gnome.ControlCenter.SearchProvider[253288]:   File "/usr/share/system-config-printer/printerproperties.py", line 579, in show

Mar 21 10:20:41 birch org.gnome.ControlCenter.SearchProvider[253288]:     self.load (name, host=host, encryption=encryption, parent=parent)

Mar 21 10:20:41 birch org.gnome.ControlCenter.SearchProvider[253288]:   File "/usr/share/system-config-printer/printerproperties.py", line 1456, in load

Mar 21 10:20:41 birch org.gnome.ControlCenter.SearchProvider[253288]:     self.add_job_option (option, value=value,

Mar 21 10:20:41 birch org.gnome.ControlCenter.SearchProvider[253288]:   File "/usr/share/system-config-printer/printerproperties.py", line 835, in add_job_option

Mar 21 10:20:41 birch org.gnome.ControlCenter.SearchProvider[253288]:     option = options.OptionWidget(name, value, supported,

Mar 21 10:20:41 birch org.gnome.ControlCenter.SearchProvider[253288]:   File "/usr/share/system-config-printer/options.py", line 100, in OptionWidget

Mar 21 10:20:41 birch org.gnome.ControlCenter.SearchProvider[253288]:     return OptionSelectOneNumber(name, v, s, on_change)

Mar 21 10:20:41 birch org.gnome.ControlCenter.SearchProvider[253288]:   File "/usr/share/system-config-printer/options.py", line 426, in __init__

Mar 21 10:20:41 birch org.gnome.ControlCenter.SearchProvider[253288]:     debugprint("Selecting from choices:", supported[0])

Mar 21 10:20:41 birch org.gnome.ControlCenter.SearchProvider[253288]: TypeError: debugprint() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

Mar 21 10:20:41 birch dbus-daemon[897]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.hostname1' unit='dbus-org.freedesktop.hostname1.service' requested 
by ':1.754' (uid=1000 pid=253288 comm="/usr/bin/python3 /usr/share/system-config-printer/" label="unconfined")
```

Comment: A picture of truncated messages does not help. Please read  https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask and https://askubuntu.com/help/formatting . Take the [tour].

Comment: I am sorry, I have looked at the mentioned links.

Comment: Oops, didn't mean to hit enter there.  When I check the Printers on Ubuntu my printer is in an error state.  I have tried restarting the printer on ubuntu but that does not help.  The only information I can find on my system is the lines listed above which are the output from my syslog file when I try to restart the printer.  This is not an image and if they are truncated it is because they are truncated in the syslog file.  Are there other areas I should look for errors?